# shell script works fine when executed in terminal, but errors out when ran as concurrent program

Tags: shell, shell-script, ksh

I'm trying to add the below string manipulation commands in my existing shell script.

```
#!/bin/ksh
y=${#text}
echo "Length of text: $y"
echo "Last _ is in column $((${#text} - ${#end}))"
echo "Our position is till column $((${#text} - ${#end}-$x))"

len=`expr $((${#text} - ${#end}-$x))`
echo $len

val=$( echo $text $len|awk '{print substr($0,0,$2)}')

echo $val
count=`ls $val*|wc -l`
echo $count
```

The above commands works fine when executed in terminal. but when i add to my existing shell script which is running as a concurrent program, the program errors out throwing the error "Bad substitution". And i'm able to identify that the it errors out at the code added recently  for string manipulations.

I can see the code is interpreted as korn shell and I've used korn shell commands only which works in terminal but when added to existing concurrent program's unix script it errors out.

Below is the code in my existing script along with newly added commands

```
#Parameters : Takes the following input parameters.
# 1) Input base directory   -- parameter 5
# 2) File Pattern           -- Parameter 6
# 3) Appl short name        -- parameter 7
# 4) appl. resp.            -- parameter 8
# 5) Debug                  -- parameter 9
#=======================================================================
#!/bin/ksh
AppsUser="$3"
BaseDir="$5"
FilePattern="$6"
AppShortName="$7"
AppResp="$8"
DebugProgram="$9"

echo "Apps User=$AppsUser"
echo "Base Directory=$BaseDir"
echo "File Pattern=$FilePattern"
echo "App Short Name=$AppShortName"
echo "App Responsibility=$AppResp"
echo "Debug Program=$DebugProgram"

IncomingDir="$BaseDir/incoming"
ProcessedDir="$BaseDir/processed"
ProcessingDir="$BaseDir/processing"
TempFile="$BaseDir/incoming/absn_psoft_glfile_search_results.txt"
ConcProgram="ABSN_PEOPLESOFT_OGL_INTF_MAIN"
echo $ConcProgram
echo $TempFile
IFS="
"
export IFS

cd $IncomingDir
ls *_GL_*.dat 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    #for i in `cat $TempFile`
    for file in `ls *_GL_*.dat`
     do
      echo "File being processed $file"
       FILENAME=$file
       #echo $FILENAME
       len=${#FILENAME} -->Error thrown for this command
       echo "The length is $len"
       if [ -s $FILENAME ]
        then
      echo "Moving file $FILENAME to $ProcessingDir"
      mv $IncomingDir/$FILENAME $ProcessingDir/$FILENAME
      echo "Submitting concurrent Request using CONCSUB for File=$FILENAME"
      CONCSUB $FCP_LOGIN $AppShortName $AppResp $AppsUser WAIT=N CONCURRENT ABSN $ConcProgram  $FILENAME 0 $DebugProgram $ProcessingDir
      echo "Submitted Request for File=$FILENAME"
      sleep 60
      else
          echo "File size is 0 bytes, moving file to processed directory"
          mv $IncomingDir/$FILENAME $ProcessedDir/$FILENAME.rmv
      fi
    done
else
  echo "No GL PSoft files to process."
fi
#echo "After if"
echo "Completed Job, Exiting program with code 0"
exit 0
```

The script is attached as an executable to an oracle concurrent program and executed using the concurrent program

Comment: You are adding it literally into the existing script? Or calling it as a command?

Comment: i'm adding it to the existing script. In the existing script i'm trying to find the length of a filename.                                                                                 ****************************************************************************                  for file in `ls *_GL_*.dat`
     do
      echo "File being processed $file"
       FILENAME=$file
          len=${#FILENAME}  ---> error thrown here
    echo "The length is $len"

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Instead, [edit] the question and add the extra information in the question, and use the comments just for short sentences, or to inform a person that you made a change.

Comment: sorry didn't know the rules for comments... Added the details to the question as per the suggestion

Comment: Is the code block on the bottom the complete script? Please post the whole script. How do you execute it when it fails?

Comment: added the complete script. The script is executed through concurrent program

Comment: When you add code, select it and press the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: done as mentioned

Comment: You hould edit your script to specify the interpreter on the *first* line. No comments (or anything else) above the `#!/bin/ksh`!

Comment: Also can someone explain me this command

Comment: What do you mean by "this command"?

Answer (score 1):

> works fine when executed in terminal. but when i add to my existing shell script which is running as a concurrent program, the program errors out throwing the error "Bad substitution".

Syntax errors in a script? That usually indicates that you aren't using the same shell for the script and interactively.

> ```
> #Parameters : Takes the following input parameters.
> …
> ```

This script has no [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), so it's executed with `sh`, not with `ksh`. On your system, `sh` is evidently an old Bourne shell that doesn't understand arithmetic expansion. You apparently meant to execute the script with ksh, but the `#!/bin/ksh` line must be the first line in the file. Move it before the usage comments.

Also, [always put double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters): `cd "$IncomingDir"` etc. And [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs): `for file in *_GL_*.dat`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out....Now i understand why half of the script got executed with output and the newly added ones were throwing error.

Comment: And nice to know the symbol #! has got a name too...Shebang...